# Laravel homestead so tough to install in windows?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I've been toying around for quiet a long time just to install laravel homestead in windows but still no luck to figure it out. I am using VirtualBox 5.1.14 and vagrant 1.9.2 and Guest 4.2.0 which is constantly saying that GuestAddition in my host and guest do not match. I am a little bit tired figuring this out that is why I am asking it here because I know some of you have figure this out. Please help me. Here is my set up. I am following the Per Project Installation documentation in laravel homestead. Thank you so much for the help.

Homestead.yaml

```
ip: 192.168.10.10
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
-
    map: 'C:\xampp\htdocs'
    to: /home/vagrant/Code/htdocs
sites:
-
    map: homestead.app
    to: /home/vagrant/Code/htdocs/Laravel/public
databases:
- homestead
name: htdocs
hostname: htdocs
```

folder structure

In my `C:\xampp\htdocs`, I have `.vagrant` folder, `Homestead.yaml` and `Vagrantfile`. And I have `Laravel` project folder inside.

And I have this line in my hosts file

```
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
```

Terminal Log:

```
# vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: xampp_default_1489894399165_80912
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
[default] GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.1.14) and guest (4.2.0) do not
 match.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fakeroot linux-headers-3.2.0-23 make patch
Suggested packages:
  make-doc diffutils-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms fakeroot linux-headers-3.2.0-23 linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic make
  patch
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.
Need to get 12.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 68.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main make amd64 3.81-8.1ubunt
u1 [118 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main patch amd64 2.6.1-3 [80.
2 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main dkms all 2.2.0.3-1ubuntu
3 [73.1 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main fakeroot amd64 1.18.2-1
[87.2 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main linux-headers-3.2.0-23 a
ll 3.2.0-23.36 [11.4 MB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main linux-headers-3.2.0-23-g
eneric amd64 3.2.0-23.36 [947 kB]
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
Fetched 12.7 MB in 1min 5s (193 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package make.
(Reading database ... 51095 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking make (from .../make_3.81-8.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package patch.
Unpacking patch (from .../patch_2.6.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
Unpacking dkms (from .../dkms_2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Unpacking fakeroot (from .../fakeroot_1.18.2-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.2.0-23.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-23 (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-23_3.2.0-23.36_al
l.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generi
c_3.2.0-23.36_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up make (3.81-8.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up patch (2.6.1-3) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.18.2-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (
fakeroot) in auto mode.
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-23 (3.2.0-23.36) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic (3.2.0-23.36) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-23-generic /boot/v
mlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic
Copy iso file C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the
 box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
mount: warning: /mnt seems to be mounted read-only.
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.1.14 - guest version is 4.2.0
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.1.14 Guest Additions for Linux...........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 4.2.0 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
vboxadd.sh: Building Guest Additions kernel modules.
vboxadd.sh: You should restart your guest to make sure the new modules are actua
lly used.
vboxadd.sh: Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions.

Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.


Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.2.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.1.14
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.2.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.1.14
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.2.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.1.14
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
Restarting VM to apply changes...
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/xampp
```

[image]

Comment: Your hosts file should point to the loopback address, `127.0.0.1`, as Homestead should forward the VM's port 80 to your host port 8000.

Comment: Also, your vagrant box doesn't appear to be [`laravel/homestead`](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead), it's [`hashicorp/precise64`](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise64)...?

Comment: Hi. thank you for responding. How would I change hashicorp/precise64 to laravel/homestead?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the [Homestead documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead) for a detailed setup guide. Everything there applies to Windows. To switch your box over to Homestead, use `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` to install the box and run `vagrant up` in the directory where you `git clone`d Homestead.